# Compare two tables to find missing rows dynamically in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a Mapping table that stores Source and destination table name. I want to compare source table data with destination table data and find out the missing rows. Table names should be passed dynamically in data flow mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Exists transformation in ADF data flows with the "Does not exists" option.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mark, but how we can pass dynamic column names. This pipeline will run for multiple tables.

Comment: Add parameters into your data flow and then use the parameter values in the exists condition

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an example syntax when using the same dynamic column name $ColumnName for both the streams? Because all I get is true because I assume the $ColumnName seems to be evaluated as a string and then "string = string" evaluates to true.

In some of the documentation it indicates inputStream@column == inputStream@column so I tried eg sourceStaging@$ColumnName == sourceWarhouse@$ColumnName... but that doesn't work either.

Comment: I figured it out... I needed to use the parameter in the byName function so in my case it is... byName( $ColumnName, "sourceStaging") .... and .... byName( $ColumnName, "sourceWarehouse")